# I'm having trouble starting a QThread

Tags: python, pyside

I'm building an application in Python using PySide. I have a GUI that is emulating some hardware which can be controlled using a Python shell. I've started the GUI in a separate process which creates it's own thread that monitors a Queue between the two processes. The main process puts commands on the queue and the queue monitor thread in the GUI Process blocks until a command is received. The queue monitor thread sends signals to the GUI to be updated.

The problem is that my queue monitor thread is not starting.

Here is the relevant code in the main process:

```
def init():
    proc_comms_q_to_em = Queue()
    proc_comms_q_from_em = Queue()
    emulator = Process(
        target=run_emulator,
        args=(sys.argv, proc_comms_q_to_em, proc_comms_q_from_em))
    emulator.start()
    sleep(1)
    proc_comms_q_to_em.put(('message', 'test'))
    print("q to em size", proc_comms_q_to_em.qsize())
```

The emulator (GUI) process:

```
class InterfaceMessageHandler(QObject):
    def __init__(self, app, q_to_em, q_from_em):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_app = app
        self.q_to_em = q_to_em
        self.q_from_em = q_from_em

    def check_queue(self):
        print("Checking queue")
        while True:
            print("Waiting for action")
            action = self.q_to_em.get()
            # emit signal so that gui gets updated


def start_interface_message_handler(
        app, emu_window, proc_comms_q_to_em, proc_comms_q_from_em):
    # need to spawn a worker thread that watches the proc_comms_q
    # need to seperate queue function from queue thread
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323678/threading-and-signals-problem
    # -in-pyqt
    intface_msg_hand_thread = QThread()
    intface_msg_hand = InterfaceMessageHandler(
        app, proc_comms_q_to_em, proc_comms_q_from_em)
    intface_msg_hand.moveToThread(intface_msg_hand_thread)
    intface_msg_hand_thread.started.connect(intface_msg_hand.check_queue)

    # connect some things to emu_window

    def about_to_quit():
        intface_msg_hand_thread.quit()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(about_to_quit)

    intface_msg_hand_thread.start()
    print("started msg handler")


def run_emulator(
        sysargv, proc_comms_q_to_em, proc_comms_q_from_em):
    app = QApplication(sysargv)

    emu_window = EmulatorWindow()

    print("gui: Starting interface message handler")
    start_interface_message_handler(
        app, emu_window, proc_comms_q_to_em, proc_comms_q_from_em)

    print("gui: showing window")
    emu_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When I run the init function I get:

```
gui: Starting interface message handler
started msg handler
gui: showing window
q to em size 1
```

My emulator window appears but I see no "Checking queue".

I've started it in the same way as this code: https://github.com/piface/pifacedigital-emulator/blob/testing/pifacedigital_emulator/gui.py#L442

Are there any gotcha's I should be watching out for? Is this the correct way of communicating between processes/threads/QT?

Comment: does it make a difference if you keep a reference to `intface_msg_hand_thread`? maybe the undelying thread gets destroyed when the instance goes out of scope.

Comment: Also, I would recommend designing signal/slot connection or event-listener for checking the queue, rather than `while True`.

Comment: Does Signal/Slot work across Processes? Is so then that would remove the entire need for a queue.