# Signal fails to emit with Chaco and PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4, chaco

I am trying to work with Chaco and pyqt in plotting a real-time data acquisition task for laboratory hardware. I was previously using matplotlib, however it proved to be too slow (I even tried animation). The following code works fine when I embedded a matplotlib plot in a pyqt window, but with chaco, nothing happens when I emit my update signal from inside a thread. This code will work if you do not use a thread for the simulated acquisition. I have tried using qthreads to no avail either (including something like this: [Threading and Signals problem in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323678/threading-and-signals-problem-in-pyqt)). Is there anyone out there who has used pyqt + chaco + threading that could help me find where I am going wrong, or what is happening?

```
import sys
import threading, time
import numpy as np

from enthought.etsconfig.etsconfig import ETSConfig
ETSConfig.toolkit = "qt4"

from enthought.enable.api import Window
from enthought.chaco.api import ArrayPlotData, Plot

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Signals(QtCore.QObject):
    done_collecting = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray, np.ndarray)

class PlotWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
        y = np.sin(x)
        plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=y)
        plot = Plot(plotdata, padding=50, border_visible=True)
        plot.plot(('x', 'y'))

        window = Window(self,-1, component=plot)
        self.setCentralWidget(window.control)
        self.resize(500,500)

        self.pd = plotdata

    def update_display(self, x, y):
        print 'updating'
        self.pd.set_data('x', x)
        self.pd.set_data('y', y)


def run_collection(signal):
    # this is where I would start and stop my hardware,
    # but I will just call the read function myself here
    for i in range(1,10):
        every_n_collected(i, signal)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def every_n_collected(frequency, signal):
    # dummy data to take place of device read
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
    y = np.sin(x*frequency)
    print 'emitting'
    signal.emit(x, y)
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

def main():
    plt = PlotWindow()
    plt.show()
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    signals = Signals()
    signals.done_collecting.connect(plt.update_display)

    t = threading.Thread(target=run_collection, args=(signals.done_collecting,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()    

    # it works without threads though...
    # run_collection(signals.done_collecting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main()
```

Comment: you never start an event loop, and don't call `processEvents` after the signal is emitted (except within the slot connected to the signal). so it's not really surprising that signals don't get delivered. what happens if you add a `processEvents` after `t.join()`?

Comment: If I add the processEvents after the t.join(), the update will execute, but only after the thread finishes, and all at once.

Comment: you should add it after `signal.emit` to allow the gui to update. there's no point in having it inside `update_display` because that won't be called unless event pocessing already takes place.

Comment: Save behaviour, I also updated the snippet to reflect changes. I had had the `processEvents` after the signal was emitted because I was thinking I had to call it to get the plot changes to take effect (this is what I had done with matplotlib), not to get the signal to emit, so that is good to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to join on the mainthread (which is the UI thread) is blocking that thread and prevents the events to be processed by the UI. If you started the app/GUI event loop in the main function and wait for the app to be closed without calling t.join(), it should work fine.

This is the way to do it with regular Traits/TraitsUI/Chaco apps.

```
import time
import threading

import numpy as np

from traits.etsconfig.etsconfig import ETSConfig
ETSConfig.toolkit = "qt4"

from enable.api import ComponentEditor
from chaco.api import ArrayPlotData, Plot

from traits.api import Event, HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import View, Item

class PlotWindow(HasTraits):

    dataset = Instance(ArrayPlotData)
    plot = Instance(Plot)

    def _dataset_default(self):
        x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
        y = np.sin(x)
        plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=y)
        return plotdata

    def _plot_default(self):
        plot = Plot(self.dataset, padding=50, border_visible=True)
        plot.plot(('x', 'y'))
        return plot

    def update_display(self, x, y):
        print 'updating', threading.current_thread()
        self.dataset.set_data('x', x)
        self.dataset.set_data('y', y)

    traits_view = View(
        Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(size=(400, 400)), show_label=False)
    )

def run_collection(datamodel):
    # this is where I would start and stop my hardware,
    # but I will just call the read function myself here
    for i in range(1,10):
        x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
        y = np.sin(x*i)
        datamodel.update_display(x, y)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def main():
    plot = PlotWindow()

    t = threading.Thread(target=run_collection, args=(plot,))
    t.start()

    # Starts the UI and the GUI mainloop
    plot.configure_traits()

    # don't call t.join() as it blocks the current thread...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That was it! If I remove the `t.join()`, and then put in an app.exec_() it will update correctly and wait for the user to close the window, or signal the app to quit. I don't need the `processEvent` calls either.